# Vue router - missing param for named route

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-router

How can I solve this problem.

I have a button which should link me to the view about the object I have created. For example

```
   <router-link :to="{ name:DetailView,
                       params:{ id: detail.id}
                     }
                @click="createDetail()> Create Detail
   </router-link>
```

And in my component `detail` is set after a backend request:

```
detail:Detail;

createDetail(){
    makeBackendCall().then(detail=>{
        this.detail=detail
    })
}
```

This is the warning/error I get:

```
[vue-router] missing param for named route "name:DetailView":
Expected "id" to match "[^\/]+?", but received ""
```

Obviously the `detail` component is not yet loaded. Is there something I am missing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should make a normal html button, and then manually redirect the user after you make your backend object (and use css to style the button)

```html
    <button @click="createDetail()"> Create Detail
    </button>
```

```js
    createDetail(){
        makeBackendCall().then(detail=>{
            this.$router.push({
                name: DetailView,
                params: {
                    id: detail.id
                }
            })
        })
    }
```

In the above code, `$router` is a link to the current active Vue router, [and there are also other methods you can call on it, to do differend things](https://router.vuejs.org/guide/essentials/navigation.html)

Answer (score 0):

This is a common mistake when you try to render 'detail.id' for the first time. Probably property 'id' is undefined. So you can do something like this to avoid that warn:

```
<router-link
    v-if="typeof detail.id !== 'undefined'" ...
```